# Proper pattern for dyadic functions in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, methods, scope

I'm having a Python program that has a hiccup and my head is spinning with the scope rules.

Suppose we have a class called Matrix.  Internally it holds a 2-D ray of numbers. So the core to instantiate it looks like:

```
z = Matrix([values])
```

so the instance z takes a list of lists and makes an instance where z.internal_matrix is an attribute holding the matrix-like list passed in.

The question I always get stuck on is this: how do you architect the code so it has maximum reliability and clarity if you're building dyadic functions like "matrix_mult"?

Note that this problem occurs less when the function you want to call is a function of one variable.  If so, in the code we can have a function like "determinant" that is monadic and refers to self.  So, I think we prefer

```
z.determinant()
```

and determinant is a function that is declared inside the class (the same as **init**).

Now suppose we have a dyadic function like multiply, called 'matrix_multiply'.  We can define that at the same level as **init**.

Now the syntax gets a little cagey - suggesting the 'calling instance' is in a sense more privileged about its data - since we might do

```
z = self.matrix_multiply(y)
```

where y is another object of the same class.  We also could have done equally well:

```
z = y.matrix_multiply((x))
```

Finally, one could create a function at some level of maxtrix_multiply.  It would be knowledgeable of all the class internals, data and methods.  We could then write:

```
z = matrix_multiply(x, y)
```

where matrix_multiply could be a member (method) of the class, OR it could be a free-standing like a FORTRAN subroutine; all it needs to know is how to instantiate a new variable by "reaching into" the object box and accessing internal routine.  Doing it this way makes clear its not a "magic" function within the bowels of a class or class instance.

However, to work, matrix_multiply must have a thorough knowledge of the class/instance variables so it can do its magic "outside" of any instance.

Trying to think of all the possibilities - and getting one to work - is draining my brain.  What is the general advice in such situations?

Comment: i would prefer the one which is fast and optimized, of course, reliability is important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably go for a `classmethod` called `multiply` on the `Matrix` class. It would be called like `z = Matrix.multiply(x, y)`. This then avoids any suggestion that one of the operands is "more privileged", and keeps all the logic related to the internals of the `Matrix` class inside the `Matrix` class.

```py
class Matrix:
    def __init__(self, values):
        ...

    @classmethod
    def multiply(cls, left: 'Matrix', right: 'Matrix') -> 'Matrix':
        ...
        return result
```

**However this is without knowing any of the rest of the context of your project/application.** For instance, it might make more sense in your application if the code looked like

```
z = x.multiply(y)
```

in which case you should implement it as a regular method on the `Matrix` class.

Finally, if you want to be able to write

```
z = x * y
```

then you need to implement the `__mul__` method on the `Matrix` class:

```py
class Matrix:
    ...
    def __mul__(self, other: 'Matrix') -> 'Matrix':
        ...
        return result
```